# Is there any software that can decode big QR code?

Tags: windows, android, linux, encryption, qr-code

As you can see at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage), QR codes can be much bigger than usually they are. By enlarging the QR, one can insert more data into them. For instance, version 40 allows to encode up to 20 MB. I have seen that one can encode any file into a big QR as shown in this [GitHub project](https://github.com/alisinabh/paperify). But, although this is a standard, I haven't been able to find any user friendly application to decode these QR. E.g. I would like to find an Android app that allow you to do it. Or if not, at least some web service. Do you know any?

PS. Why do I want this? I would like to “print” a Zip file on a piece of physical paper so that any user could obtain it by just pointing with a phone camera. Links can be removed with time and I would prefer to encode my data into a picture that will rest for ever. Of course, if there is something better I would be happy to know about them :) But to me it was quite simple this QR stuff...